# Get value of span that is dynamically changed by a select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, html

I have an ecommerce website with a `<span>` that contains the SKU of each product on the product detail page as follows:

```
<span class="VariationProductSKU">052077</span>
```

When the customer selects a size in the following `<select>` menu...

```
<div class="productOptionViewSelect">
     <select id="4ab0094cccc675de3daaa83d6b1819e2" class="validation" name="attribute[110]">
          <option selected="selected" value=""> -- Please Choose an Option -- </option>
          <option value="69">S</option>
          <option value="70">M</option>
          <option value="71">L</option>
          <option value="72">XL</option>
          <option value="73">XXL</option>
     </select>
</div>
```

the SKU displayed in the `<span>` tag is dynamically updated as follows (in this example, they selected size "L"):

```
<span class="VariationProductSKU">052077.L</span>
```

I need to get the value of the `<span>` tag containing the new dynamically updated SKU using jQuery. I've tried the following jQuery code, but it seems to always be passing me back the previous value of the `<span>` tag and not the new value.

```
if ($('div.productAttributeList').html() !== ''){
    $("div.productOptionViewSelect select").on( 'change', function () {
         var val = "";
         val = $('span.VariationProductSKU').text().trim();
         alert(val);
    });
}
```

Any insight into how I can get the correct value from the `<span>` tag would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where are you updating that spans content?

Comment: The span's content is being updated by a remote jQuery script that I do not have access to. This happens automatically whenever the select element is changed.

Comment: @user2908769 What is remote jquery script are you using some plugin?

Comment: Seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/pRCs8/

Comment: _"a remote jQuery script that I do not have access to"_ a whu?

Comment: I am guessing that the onchange that you are using is being called before the onchange that updates the text.

Comment: Well...you may have to set a timeout then before you grab the value

Comment: My site is hosted by a third party. I do not have access to every file, and instead only have access to template files. In other words, I cannot edit any of their jQuery code myself. I can only write my own code on top of it within a template file. Does this help to clarify?

Comment: The idea of a timeout sounds promising, I'll see if I can come up with something that will work based on that thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try waiting a bit for the remote script to finish:

```
if ($('div.productAttributeList').html() !== '') {
    $("div.productOptionViewSelect select").on('change', function () {
        var val = "";

        setTimeout(function() {
            val = $('span.VariationProductSKU').text().trim();
            alert(val);
        }, 50); // adjust this value until it's working reliably
    });
}
```

Comment: This seems to work perfectly, my only concern is how long I had to increase the timeout to (1000). I also wonder if this value will change depending on the remote server's current traffic and load. I'll keep playing with this and see if I can find the ideal amount of time to set the timeout to. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Yeah, that's the drawback to using setTimeout as opposed to a proper callback on the span update function.